# IF conditions by pair of conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this loop that checks the following conditions. For each iteration of `i` one needs to get a value for `m1, m2, m3, m4 and m5`. Do the `if` statements need to be checked like this (by "pairs") or is there a smarter/faster way of doing it?

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):

    if      df.ix[i, 'ema4'] >= df.ix[i, 'ema9']:
            m1 = 1
    elif    df.ix[i, 'ema4'] < df.ix[i, 'ema9']:
            m1 = -1

    if      df.ix[i, 'ema9'] >= df.ix[i, 'ema20']:
            m2 = 1            
    elif    df.ix[i, 'ema9'] < df.ix[i, 'ema20']:
            m2 = -1

    if      df.ix[i, 'ema20'] >= df.ix[i, 'ema48']:
            m3 = 1
    elif    df.ix[i, 'ema20'] < df.ix[i, 'ema48']:
            m3 = -1        

    if      df.ix[i, 'ema48'] >= df.ix[i, 'ema80']:
            m4 = 1
    elif    df.ix[i, 'ema48'] < df.ix[i, 'ema80']:
            m4 = -1  

    if      df.ix[i, 'ema80'] >= df.ix[i, 'ema100']:
            m5 = 1
    elif    df.ix[i, 'ema80'] < df.ix[i, 'ema100']:
            m5 = -1 

    df.ix[i,'test'] = (m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5)
```

Comment: Have you really not heard of `else`?

Comment: I guess you could replace all these `elif ...` with a simple `else`

Comment: Or just `m1 = (condition)*2-1` if you really don't want to use branches for some reason.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, yes I was also using it, but my question was more in the line of what eugene y  answered. Also, if I understand correclty. When using 'else' for each pair instead of 'elif', it should be faster as it evaluates less expressions?

Comment: Yes, there is that performance benefit as well. Also keep in mind that if you're checking the result of a function call, you might not want to call the function twice (due to side effects). If you're familiar with `else`, why were you using `elif` here? It doesn't make any sense to check for something that must logically be true.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 just wanted to be 100% sure I was checking all conditions and as you see I wasn't totally confident in my  understanding of 'else'. thanks for the help.

Comment: For future reference, the only time you might want to use `if..elif` in this manner (with mutually exclusive predicates) is if you think the values you're checking might be changing as you're running this part of the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simplify the code, you could initialize the variables to the default value and use a bunch of `if`s:

```
m1 = m2 = m3 = m4 = m5 = -1

for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if df.ix[i, 'ema4'] >= df.ix[i, 'ema9']:
        m1 = 1
    ...
```

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 loops, one which is mentioned by @eugene y with slightly modification for lists and another with you columns:

```
df_size = len(df.index)
m = [-1] * df_size 
col_names = ['ema4', 'ema9', 'ema20', 'ema48', 'ema80']

for i in range(df_size ):
     for col_name in col_names:
          if df.ix[i, col_name] >= df.ix[i, col_name ]:
               m[i] = 1


df.ix[i,'test'] = sum(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like comments said just use else:

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if df.ix[i, 'ema4'] >= df.ix[i, 'ema9']:
        m1 = 1
    else:
        m1 = -1
```

or you could preset and just do the if:

```
    m1 = -1
    if df.ix[i, 'ema4'] >= df.ix[i, 'ema9']:
        m1 = 1
```

repeat for all ifs

Comment: That `for..else` is technically valid, but it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: just saw that - fixed it - oops